# How to render template after failed form validation?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('employee/add_employee/', views.add_employee, name='add-employee'),
    path('employee/add_employee/add/', views.add_employee_action, name='add-employee-action'),
]
```

I have `add-employee` page and some forms to fill there.

views.py:

```py
def add_employee(request):
    personal_form = PersonalEmployeeForm()
    history_form = EmployeeHistoryForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'sections/add_employee.html',
        context={
            'personal_form': personal_form,
            'history_form': history_form,
            }
    )

def add_employee_action(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        personal_form = PersonalEmployeeForm(request.POST)
        history_form = EmployeeHistoryForm(request.POST)
        if personal_form.is_valid() and history_form.is_valid():
            # here is some logic with models
            return redirect('add-employee')
    else:
        personal_form = PersonalEmployeeForm()
        history_form = EmployeeHistoryForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'sections/add_employee.html',
        context={
            'personal_form': personal_form,
            'history_form': history_form,
        }
    )
```

template:

```html
<form id="a-submit-form" action="add/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="column-wrapper">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    {% for field in personal_form.visible_fields %}
                        {% include "elements/forms/form_line.html" %}
                        <br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    {% for field in history_form.visible_fields %}
                        {% include "elements/forms/form_line.html" %}
                        <br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-bar-wrapper">
            <div class="button_bar">
                <a class="a-button positive" id="submit">Добавить</a>
                <a class="a-button" href="{% url 'employee' %}">Сотрудники</a>
                <a class="a-button" href="{% url 'index' %}">На главуную</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Submitting by `<a>` element is tested and worked well with jQuery script.

The problem is after submitting invalid forms I have a page with `blah-blah/employee/add_employee/add/` URL. And if I try to submit forms again I have a page with `blah-blah/employee/add_employee/add/add/` URL, which is incorrect. How can I render the  page with `blah-blah/employee/add_employee/` URL and show all error messages?

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that use a *relative* url in the `action=...` of the `<form>`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, it has ```action="add/"```. But how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show your templates as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you have written a *relative* URL in the `<form>` tag of the `sections/add_employee.html` template. The template thus contains something like:

```
<form method="post" action="add/">
    ...
</form>
```

You can use a URL with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add-employee-action' %}">
    ...
</form>
```

Furthermore one usually uses the *same* path to handle both the GET and the POST request. So in fact you might simply remove the `'add-employee'` path.